# Как приконектиться к MariaDB в Docker?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

У меня фулстек приложение, я хочу поднять его в докере!
Cобрал 3 контейнера для запуска проекта в докере:
*Клиент(Nuxt), Сервер(Node/Express), База(MariaDB)*

При попытке приконектиться я получаю такую ошибку

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3006
```

Вот мой код

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  server:
    build: server/
    command: [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
    ports:
      - 3005:3005
    volumes:
      - .:/server
    working_dir: /app

  client:
    build: client/
    command: [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/client
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - server

  maria:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
      - 3006:3306
    volumes:
      - .:/migrate
    working_dir: /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=nodejs
```

Настройки подключения к базе

```
"database" : {
    "host"     : "localhost",
    "port"     : "3006",
    "user"     : "nodejs",
    "password" : "nodejs",
    "database" : "travelpriceoff",
    "insecureAuth": true,
    "multipleStatements": true
}
```

Вот лог ответа в консоле когда пытаюсь дернуть базу данных

```
travelpriceoff-server-1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3006
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     --------------------
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at Connection._implyConnect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:454:10)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at Connection.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:196:8)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at /app/functions.js:13:24
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at Object.returnDocumentHead (/app/functions.js:12:22)
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at /app/main.js:32:33
travelpriceoff-server-1  |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) {
travelpriceoff-server-1  |   errno: -111,
travelpriceoff-server-1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
travelpriceoff-server-1  |   syscall: 'connect',
travelpriceoff-server-1  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
travelpriceoff-server-1  |   port: 3006,
travelpriceoff-server-1  |   fatal: true
travelpriceoff-server-1  | }
travelpriceoff-server-1  |
travelpriceoff-server-1  | Node.js v18.12.1
travelpriceoff-server-1  | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Я в Docker новичек, так что могу что-то не понимать, возможно я допустил ошибку, но не могу понять где именно

Comment: Я в докере тоже не особо опытный, но вроде как, вы должны коннектится к БД по имени сервиса. Попробуйте вместо *  127.0.0.1:3006  *  - * maria:3006  *

Comment: и в настройках подключения к базе, также заменить host на "maria"

Comment: Спасибо большое за этот комментарий, да это действительно сработало, можете написать в ответе я отмечу как принятый ответ!

Comment: О класс! Ровно 10 дней назад эту же беду тут пытал у людей )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При работе с Докером и использовании Docker Compose (несколько сервисов) общения между данными сервисами следует организовывать с помощью использования названий сервисов в качестве хостов. Поэтому в случае автора следует использовать **maria** вместо **IP 127.0.0.1** и вместо **localhost** при подключении БД.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!